# Valgrind memory leak detection

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind

I am new to Valgrind, and I wanted to see how valgrind works. I wrote a sample program for memory leak. However Valgrind does not seem to detect a memory leak. Can you please tell me why? Or does the below code leak memory?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test {
        private:
                int a;
        public:
                test(int c) {
                        a = c;
                }
};

int main() {
        test* t = new test(7);
}
```

this is the valgrind output

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
==5449==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5449==   total heap usage: 29 allocs, 29 frees, 3,592 bytes allocated
==5449== 
==5449== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

Comment: Valgrind should report memory leak for this code. Are you using static linking? See http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.hiddenbug

Comment: Yes, it did. I have been using the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that constitutes a memory leak; the memory at  pointer `t` is not 'lost' until t goes out of scope, and that's at the end of `main()` so there's no memory loss.

```
dan@rachel ~ $ g++ -o t t.cpp
dan@rachel ~ $ valgrind ./t
==11945== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11945== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11945== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11945== Command: ./t
==11945==
==11945==
==11945== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11945==     in use at exit: 36 bytes in 9 blocks
==11945==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 0 frees, 36 bytes allocated
==11945==
==11945== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11945==    definitely lost: 36 bytes in 9 blocks
==11945==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11945==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11945==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11945==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11945== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==11945==
==11945== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11945== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

The code was modified slightly to use `test* t` multiple times in a `for` loop, effectively "forgetting" all but the last `test` object.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class test {
  private:
    int a;
  public:
    test(int c){
      a = c;
    }
};

int main(){
  test* t;
  for(int i=1; i<10;i++)
    t=new test(i);
}
```

For even better memory leak patching, try compiling with debugging information and using the valgrind option recommended in the output:

```
dan@rachel ~ $ g++ -g -o t t.cpp
dan@rachel ~ $ valgvalgrind --leak-check=full ./t
==11981== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11981== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11981== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11981== Command: ./t
==11981==
==11981==
==11981== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11981==     in use at exit: 36 bytes in 9 blocks
==11981==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 0 frees, 36 bytes allocated
==11981==
==11981== 36 bytes in 9 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==11981==    at 0x4C2C099: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11981==    by 0x4006EF: main (t.cpp:15)
==11981==
==11981== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11981==    definitely lost: 36 bytes in 9 blocks
==11981==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11981==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11981==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11981==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11981==
==11981== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11981== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Comment: Dan, thank you. My initial code worked now. Looks like I have been running the valgrind with incorrect syntax. Thanks for the trouble.!!

Comment: Glad I could help!  Also make sure to check out `--leak-check=full` and remember, if you compile your code with debugging information you'll get line numbers of the leaks.  ( I updated the code to show the `-g` argument to `g++` and the updated output ).

Answer (score 0):

Try allocating t to another test object - i.e.

```
int main() {
        test* t = new test(7);
        t = new test(7);
        t = new test(8); // and so on...
}
```

I believe each time t is assigned to another memory location, without freeing the previously allocated memory will constitute a leak (unless your compiler is smart enough to see that the allocated memory is never used and does something clever -- in which case, be doubly certain by creating some sample variables that use t , before reassigning t and maybe even return one of those variables...)